# Read some content of a resource on internet

Tags: iphone

For my iPhone application I need to read some content of a plain html file on the web. It's just some text within a pre-tag. However I don't want to download the whole file and then get the line I need.

The format is:

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText

I only need the first line and then close the connection to that resource.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer : Don't.

Details : If the file is too big, I suggest that you implement that extraction behavior at server side and if you don't owe the server, you could even put that code on an other server that you owe and keep some cache there.

Comment: Agreed, it's too much work for very little gain to try to grab only a portion, unless it's really large.